# How to decorate component from class in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-decorator

I want to change component's decorator from class in angular4 application.

Something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BooksService } from './../books.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'users',
  templateUrl: this.template,
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})

export class UsersComponent {
  users: any;
  template: any = './users.component.html';

  constructor(private booksService : BooksService) {
    this.users = this.booksService.getItems();
  }
}
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: You cannot do what you have in your code. But, you should take a look at this: [dynamic-component-loader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decorator is not part of the class, so the `this` inside the decorator doesn't refer to the component.

It would *technically* be possible to do so using static classes:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'users',
  templateUrl: UsersComponent.template,
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})

export class UsersComponent {
  users: any;
  public static template: any = './users.component.html';
}
```

...but this would be completely useless, as a static value would just be the same as hardcoding it. 
Thankfully, Angular really doesn't require any variables to be used in decorators. It wouldn't work anyway; it compiles these templates behind the scenes with the components and changing the template would break the compiler (*especially* the AOT compiler).

Are you trying to change the html for a component? Using the `Router` or structural directives is usually a better idea.

A more direct approach to switching out the template for a component would be to use a [dynamic component](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html) that accesses other components' `TemplateRef`s directly and can swap them out with the view.